# Busybox initramfs Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, initramfs

Ubuntu starts a busybox initramfs. I've tried `exit` command and this is the last few lines of the result:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
    - Check rootdelay= (did system wait long enough?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=9eab400f-420c-9075-b9f395550097 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

And then a busybox shell again.
What's the problem and how should I fix it?

PS: the output of `cat /proc/modules` isn't empty (some kernel modules are loaded)
The output of `cat /proc/cmdline` is

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-53-generic root=UUID=9eab400f-420c-9075-b9f395550097 ro quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor
```

Comment: What did you do before this happened. It looks like `/etc/fstab` entry for the boot partition is wrong.

Comment: I changed the boot mode to UEFI and reverted back to legacy support, also changed SATA controller to compatible and then back to AHCI. @Pilot6

Comment: Check if UUID match in `blkid` and `fstab`.

Comment: How? `cat etc/fstab` is empty. @Pilot6

Comment: Boot with a LiveUSB and check. And it is `/etc/fstab`. If UUID doesn't match, the system won't boot.

Comment: If that'd be the case, is it possible to fix it using `boot-repair`? @Pilot6